# How to acess name attribute of iframe in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, react-hooks

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./MainText.css"
import "./App.css";
import FormatColorFillIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatColorFill';
import BorderColorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/BorderColor';

function MainText() {
    
    function enableEditMode() {
        textPart.document.designMode = 'On';
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        enableEditMode();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="mainText">

            <div className="mainText__second">
                <iframe name="textPart" frameBorder="0" ></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
     )
```

I have only shown the main part of the code where I am not getting my result.
I want to access the name attribute of the iframe tag but it is showing me textPart is not defined.
I also tried by putting id in the iframe and doing document.getElementById but it is also not working.
Help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this to get element by name:
`document.getElementsByName('textPart')`

So in your case the enableEditMode code will be:

```
  function enableEditMode() {
    const textpart = document.getElementsByName('textPart')[0];
    const iframeDocument= textpart.contentDocument || textpart.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDocument.designMode = "on";
  }
```

Comment: It is saying: can not set the property 'designMode' of undefined.

Comment: Iframe components do not have a document property.
I updated the code above, try that.

Comment: still not working. saying "Cannot read property 'document' of undefined";

Comment: I think I finally cracked it. The getElementsByName() returns an array, so you need to get the first element. 
So if you try the code above it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it supposed to be like this

`<iframe name={"textPart"} frameBorder="0" ></iframe>`

Comment: No, it is still saying textPart is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

function MainText() {

```
    function enableEditMode(textPart) {
        if(!textPart){
        return;} // check for iframe content
        textPart.contentWindow.addEventListener("load", () => {
               textPart.document.designMode = 'On'; // check content iframe when iframe loaded
        });
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        enableEditMode();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="mainText">

            <div className="mainText__second">
                <iframe ref={this.enableEditMode} name="textPart" frameBorder="0" >/iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
```

Have u tried [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to change iframe content?

Comment: After adding ref in iframe. "Cannot read property 'enableEditMode' of undefined" this error is coming.